# Image Processing: Separate Yellow and Blue Channels in Lab Color Space

Tags: image-processing, rgb, scikit-image, lab-color-space

I'm new to image processing, and I was given a task to separate the yellow (+ve values) and blue (-ve values) colors by a white edge from an image that contains only blue and yellow colors.

Unfortunately, I don't know how should I separate both colors.

Also, I cannot see any negative values in the pixels of the image which I got.

Unfortunately, I cannot use an advanced libraries such as `OpenCv` and most of the tutorials related to image processing on the Internet uses it.

[image: the image I used]

I converted the image from `RGB` to `Lab` color space. I'm using Python for this and `scikit-image` library and other useful packages.

I'll be glad if anyone could help by giving me any hints!

Thanks

Comment: You “can’t use advanced libraries like OpenCV”, but you can use scikit-image? Is that not an advanced library then? I mean, I would applaud your professor for explicitly excluding OpenCV, I don’t like that library at all. But maybe you misunderstood?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find a colourspace where the yellows and the blues are well separated. Splitting the channels, and assigning them across the page, in `RGB` colourspace (with R on the left, G in the centre and B on the right):

RGB without edge detection:

[image]

RGB with edge detection:

[image]

that's not very good - the brighter tones of yellow where the material is catching the light are being treated like edges.

Let's try `Lab` instead of `RGB` with `L` on the left, `a` in the centre and `b` on the right:

Lab without edge detection:

[image]

Lab with edge detection:

[image]

Still not so good. Now let's try `HSV` [colourspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV), `H` on the left, `S` in the centre and `V` on the right:

HSV without edge detection:

[image]

HSV with edge detection:

[image]

And hopefully you can see that `H` on the left nails it. That's because yellow is 60 degrees and blue is 240 degrees in [this diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#/media/File:HSL-HSV_hue_and_chroma.svg) so your two colours are diametrically opposed - or whatever hexagons have in place of a circle's diameter.

Then you need to do edge detection, and fattening, then you can composite the white edge over the top of the yellow and blue flag by choosing a *"lighten"* blend mode where you choose the lighter pixel at each location in the images so that the white edges filter through the blue and yellow.